# CSS not working for jquery ui datepicker using different themes themes

Tags: jquery, css, datepicker, themes

I'm trying to use the jquery datepicker within wordpress. I'm using different jquery ui themes and follow the tutorial at http://filamentgroup.com/lab/using_multiple_jquery_ui_themes_on_a_single_page/. Sadly, the widget is not rendering correctly, i.e. taking another css definitions.

This is the the style block:

```
<!-- PAGE: Home -->
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Sperta &raquo; Home Kommentar-Feed" href="http://localhost/wordpress/home/feed/" />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='admin-bar-css'  href='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-include /css/admin-bar.min.css?ver=3.5.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='jqueryui_css-css'  href='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/Lotus/css/jqueryui/custom.css?ver=1.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='screen_css-css'  href='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/Lotus/css/screen.css?ver=1.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='fancybox_css-css'  href='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/Lotus/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.0.css?ver=1.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='videojs_css-css'  href='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/Lotus/js/video-js.css?ver=1.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='vim_css-css'  href='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/Lotus/js/skins/vim.css?ver=1.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='jquery_ui_smoothness_css-css'  href='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/Lotus/css/smoothness/custom.css?ver=1.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='mycss_css-css'  href='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/Lotus/css/mycss.css?ver=1.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='agm_google_maps_user_style-css'  href='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-google-maps/css/google_maps_user.css?ver=3.5.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

This is the input for datepicker:

```
<tr><td class="left-column"><label for="starts-at">Starts at:</label><div class="smoothness"><input id="starts-at" class="required" name="starts-at" type="text" style="width:80px;"/></div></td>
```

Anyway, the datepicker is getting the tr, th etc. definitions from the screen.css instead of the smoothness theme.

This is the firebug output:

[image: Firebug Output]

This is how it is been rendered.

[image: The way it is rendered]

What I'm doing wrong?

Ant.